# Rewrite scroll event or falsely trigger scroll event

Tags: javascript, iframe-resizer, aos.js

Would someone be able to help me out recoding some of the aos.js script? Long story short, I'm trying to get aos to work within an iFrame. I'm using iframeResizer.js and I'm able send the height of the viewport from the parent page to the iFrame. I'm also able to send the scroll offset. The next bit I need to figure out is how to use this data within aos.js. So far I've managed to change anything within aos.js that was previously using the height and scroll position of the window to instead use the height and scroll position of the parent page, which looks promising. Where previously all aos animations were playing as soon as the page loaded, now they sit waiting for a scroll event to trigger. The thing is though, there's some code within aos.js that I just can't get my head around in order to rewrite it to trigger the scroll off a callback from iframeResizer.js. I've been trying to get these scroll based animations running within an iFrame for what seems like an eternity so any help would be greatly appreciated.

So, from what I can see, there's a line in aos.js with 3 event listeners the last of which is a scroll event. It looks like this though with some strange parameters in brackets that I've never seen before.

`window.addEventListener("scroll", (0, u.default)(function() {}`

I've tried writing my own function but I just don't get what what the (0, u.default) part is or how to use it. The whole aos.js script is way above my level of JavaScript unfortunately. If any one can advise me how I could trigger that same event listener I would very much appreciate it!

Another option I've been trying is to fake the scroll event...as in, every time the scroll position changes and gets sent from the parent into my iframe could I fake a scroll event...but I haven't had any luck. Is that even possible I wonder?

I think that's enough information for now as but if anyone is willing to help and would like more please just shout.

Thanks

Comment: On what line exactly? https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/blob/next/src/js/aos.js - There's also some documentation on the GitHub pages: https://github.com/michalsnik/aos.

Comment: Hi Roko, so in the compiled file there's a block of code from lines 78 - 90. There's a resize event listener, an orientationchange listener and then the scroll one. The resize works already even with in the iFrame.